# Disable unattended upgradeds

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I attempted to disable ubuntu unattended upgrades by completely uninstalling the package
`unattended-upgrades`.
However, today I boot into a system that broke itself again by installing a new version of cuda and nvidia drivers which again broke my setup for work. Is there a way to disable unattended upgrades altogeher that actually works?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar

I tried to put some packages on hold before, but the installation broke nevertheless (I think some dependencies updated).

Comment: Uninstall of the `unattended-upgrades` package is enough. If you already did that, then something else is going on. Review your logs to determine what packages were changed, when, and triggered by what.